# Relationship between a virtual page and cacheline

Tags: caching, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have a question on a OS virtual page and a CPU cacheline. 
Basically, OS manages 4kb sized virtual page. 
However, a cacheline is only 64b. 
So I can see that a page consists of 64 * 64b cacheline. 
If an OS request for a page, does a page gets mapped to 64 cachlines? 
How does a page gets mapped to a cacheline? 
Then does memory controller request 64 times to memory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS allocates space for new pages in physical memory (RAM) which is not organized in terms of cache lines. On allocating a new page, OS will allocate 4kB space in physical memory for this new page.

When a processor first reads or writes to some address in this newly allocated page, it will cause a cache miss. The cache will send a cache line fetch request to the memory controller. The memory controller will then fetch appropriate 64 bytes (cache line) from that page and send it to the requesting cache.

Comment: Correct, I would only add that the physical memory *is* organized logically in cache lines (although physically it's split into banks and rows, and so on). Each line has an address in the physical memory space, and it is associated with it. Therefore, when a page is allocated, all the lines in that 4k range "belong" to the OS, and it (or the app that requested that range) may begin to write into that range once the OS took care of the page mapping.